# R: clusters in histogram

Tags: r, histogram, clustered-index

I've got 6000 reports. For each report, I've got how many garbage there is in the report. So I can make a histogram of this:

```
boundaries = seq(0,1 , by=0.01) 
hist(hoeveel_rommel_per_rapport, breaks=boundaries)
```

where `hoeveel_rommel_per_rapport` is a vector that describes the garbage for each reports.
[image]

Now I've got a cluster number for each report. I want to give all the clusters a different color in the histogram. Is this possible?

So for example, the first stack contains 3 different clusters, so it gets 3 colors.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be inclined to use `ggplot` for something like this. Here are some approaches using made up data (in future, you should provide your data, or at least a representative sample).

```
set.seed(1)   # for reproducible example
reports <- data.frame(garbage=rchisq(900,c(10,15,20))/50,cluster=LETTERS[1:3])
```

This is seems like what you were looking for - a stacked histogram.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(reports) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=garbage, fill=cluster),binwidth=0.01)
```

[image]

This puts the three histograms in different panels - much clearer.

```
ggplot(reports) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=garbage, fill=cluster),binwidth=0.01) +
  facet_wrap(~cluster,nc=1)
```

[image]

Overlapping density plots in one panel.

```
ggplot(reports) +
  stat_density(aes(x=garbage, fill=cluster),position="identity",alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the argument `col` with the colors you want, I am not sure if by passing a list of colors like `col = c("green", "red", "blue")` will do what you want, but you can certainly select which color do they have

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I know this argument but I want to give each cluster a different color.

Comment: Could you post then what have you tried and a reproducible example?

Comment: I've haven't tried anything because I don't know how to do this

Comment: And what have you researched?